# Minimize the LOCK time of the file

Tags: .net, file, locking

I am working on a application which reads a file and after processing saves it back. I have to keep file in a stream while the file is in the processing. Now the issue is that I have to minimize the LOCK time of the file. 
What is the solution?

Comment: Solution: Minimize the time the file is locked ("opened" in such a mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to keep your file in `MemoryStream`. When you write to a `MemoryStream`, the data is stored in memory instead of being stored to the file system. After the processing you can then call `MemoryStream.WriteTo` to store the data on the file system permanently. This will minimize the lock time.

Comment: ...assuming that there is measurable time it generating the output itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file handle with a ShareMode of which allows other processes to access the file. In other words, you can read the file without creating an exclusive lock:

```
FileStream stream = File.Open("path", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```